# What's the "system trust roots on the apiserver" for the "caBundle" in defination of "WebhookClientConfig" of Kubernetes

Tags: ssl, kubernetes

When I check the definition of "WebhookClientConfig" of API of Kubernetes I found comments like this:

```
// `caBundle` is a PEM encoded CA bundle which will be used to validate the webhook's server certificate.
// If unspecified, system trust roots on the apiserver are used.
// +optional
CABundle []byte `json:"caBundle,omitempty" protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=caBundle"`
```

in [WebhookClientConfig](https://github.com/kubernetes/api/blob/508b64175e9264c2a4b42b1b81d2571bf036cf09/admissionregistration/v1beta1/types.go#L555)

I wonder to know, what's exactly the "system trust roots "?
and I'm afraid the internal signer for CSR API of Kubernetes is not one of them.

Answer (score 1):

It is a good practice to use secure network connections. A Webhook-endpoint in Kubernetes is typically an endpoint in a private network. A custom private CABundle can be used to generate the TLS certificate to achieve a secure [connection](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/#contacting-the-webhook) within the cluster. See e.g. [contacting the webhook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/#contacting-the-webhook).

> Webhooks can either be called via a URL or a service reference, and can optionally include a custom CA bundle to use to verify the TLS connection.

This CABundle is optional. See also [service reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/#service-reference) for how to connect.

> If the webhook is running within the cluster, then you should use service instead of url. The service namespace and name are required. The port is optional and defaults to 443. The path is optional and defaults to "/".

> Here is an example of a mutating webhook configured to call a service on port "1234" at the subpath "/my-path", and to verify the TLS connection against the ServerName my-service-name.my-service-namespace.svc using a custom CA bundle

Comment: Thanks @Jonas, but I want to know what exactly means of "system trust roots on the apiserver".  in my case, I use CSR API in kubernetes to generate my TLS certificate for my webhook and leave the "caBundle" emplty but I get “x509 Certificate Signed by Unknown Authority”.  That's means the kubernestes internal signer's CA not trust by system, so again, what's exactly the "system trust CA"? thanks

Comment: @vincentpli System trust roots on the apiserver are simply default trusted root certificates available on your node, where api server is running. Depending on the type of node's OS, they can be in following location: for example Linux-Ubuntu:`/usr/share/ca-certificates/`. As for `x509` errors, please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of how exactly are you trying to create the certificiate (with CSR) for this webhook.